# Javascript how to work with event listeners and promises

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await, local-storage, composition

Hey I'm currently learning how promises work loading up my Local Storage with an object that I receive from an API using async functions, the code actually works but I have a problem when I try to cycle through an array that I created with the response object, I have two buttons that cycle through the array elements one by one but they don't work unless the page is reloaded, if I check my console I can see the object in my Local Storage and this error pops up:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null
    at Object.nextJoke (bundle.js:10332)
    at HTMLDivElement.jokeContainer.addEventListener.event`.

My current code is:

JS::

```
const jokeContainer = document.querySelector('.joke-container');
const jokesArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('jokesData'));

// Fetch joke count from API endpoint
async function sizeJokesArray() {
  let url = 'https://api.icndb.com/jokes/count';
  let data = await (await fetch(url)).json();
  data = data.value;
  return data;
}

// use API endpoint to fetch the jokes and store it in an array
async function fetchJokes() {
  let url = `https://api.icndb.com/jokes/random/${length}`;
  let jokesData = [];
  let data = await (await fetch(url)).json();
  data = data.value;
  for (jokePosition in data) {
    jokesData.push(data[jokePosition].joke);
  }
  return localStorage.setItem('jokesData', JSON.stringify(jokesData));
}

if (jokesArray === null) {
  sizeJokesArray()
    .then(size => (length = size)) // Size of array in response
    .then(fetchJokes);
}

const jokeDispenser = (function() {
  let counter = 0; //start counter at position 0 of jokes array
  function _change(position) {
    counter += position;
  }
  return {
    nextJoke: function() {
      _change(1);
      counter %= jokesArray.length; // start from 0 if we get to the end of the array
      return jokesArray[counter];
    },
    prevJoke: function() {
      if (counter === 0) {
        counter = jokesArray.length; // place our counter at the end of the array
      }
      _change(-1);
      return jokesArray[counter];
    }
  };
})();

// pass selected joke to print on html element
function printJoke(joke) {
  document.querySelector('.joke-text p').textContent = joke;
}

jokeContainer.addEventListener('click', event => {
  if (event.target.value === 'Next') {
    printJoke(jokeDispenser.prevJoke(jokesArray));
  } else if (event.target.value === 'Prev') {
    printJoke(jokeDispenser.nextJoke(jokesArray));
  }
});
```

HTML::

```
<body>
  <div class="joke-container">
    <div class="joke-text">
      <p>Fetch some jokes bro!!</p>
    </div>
    <div class="joke-controls">
      <button type="button" value="Prev">Prev</button>
      <button type="button" value="Next">Next</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

I'm aware that my problem has to do with my promise chaining or composition but after reading [Google Promises](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/promises)
and [MDN Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) I don't really get how to approach this problem.

Comment: I may be missing something here - where are you using `promise` on your code? I do see you await on the url response - is that what you are referring to?

Comment: What exactly is your problem?

Comment: @Jaya If I'm not wrong `fetch()` returns a promise containing a response object, in this case from the URL provided.

Comment: @IzumiSy I edited the question now, when I was formatting I deleted that part, thanks for noticing.

Comment: Thank you. Could you paste your html too?

Comment: It looks `length` in fetchJokes function is undefined.

Comment: Yes, it's undefined until I refresh the page.

Comment: An interesting twist... you code works fine in Firefox.

Comment: @Zze In mine it doesn't, remember to delete Local Storage on every reload because after first reload it will always work.

Comment: @Kaiido Yes, that's exactly what the error says, what should I check about the response?

Comment: Ah I finally got it while running your code. The first time you run it, `jokesArray` is null since not yet in your localStorage. But when you parse it, you don't assign `jokesArray = jokesData`, you only save it in the localStorage. So `jokesArray` remains null, even after you fetched it. So to fix this typo, change `jokesArray` to be a `let` and set it in `fetchJokes`  as `jokesArray = jokesData`. https://jsfiddle.net/0nj7efgb/

Comment: @Kaiido Amazing, that indeed fixes my problem, you should post it as an answer!.